# Windows 10 Sticky Notes App sync issues

Tags: windows-10, sync, microsoft-onenote, cloud, sticky-notes

We have an active directory environment. This is synced to Azure. We also have office 365 licenses assigned to several users.
However, when signing in to the sticky notes app we receive an error.

> We couldn't verify your sign-in info. No valid Office 365 subscription was found and we can't save your notes.

I found the notes should sync to [OneNote site](https://www.onenote.com/stickynotes). In fact, OneNote itself does sync but sticky notes on the cloud also states No Exchange subscription found.

So my question is what subscription is required to accomplish this, or what needs to be configured to be able to sync?

Comment: Does your current license include Mail? It would be important to separate what you're looking at as OneNote and Outlook both support notes. It might be that sticky notes is meant to build up on Outlook notes rather than OneNote notes. Where did you find that it should sync to OneNote notes? Your link just points to the cloud version of sticky notes?

Comment: The license does include mail. There are several articles that state that version 3 would have the sticky notes app sync to the cloud and gave the onenote url as the location of the sync. Plus it’s on the onenote url the exchange error shows as well.

Comment: I'll add, we currently have the office 365 e5 subscription which include both mail and use of office applications.

Comment: I would wrap this as a request to Microsoft Office sales department as follows: With our (...) subscription we are getting the (...) error, what subscription do we actually need in order to make this working?