# Sticky Notes error "We couldn't verify your sign-in info"

Tags: windows-10, office365, microsoft-onenote, sticky-notes

On a Windows 10 v1809 PC, I'm trying to sign into Sticky Notes v3.6.76.0 (latest) using my Office 365 user account. Consistently, it prompts for and accepts the credentials (password then MFA / TFA code), spins on "Just a moment..." for a minute or so, and then fails with the following error:

> We couldn't verify your sign-in info.

[image]

Unlike other cases ([link 1](https://superuser.com/questions/1416358/windows-10-sticky-notes-app-sync-issues), [link 2](https://superuser.com/questions/1463903/sticky-notes-error-0x80072efd)), there is no additional error information.

In my diagnostics, I have found that:

- Microsoft Office apps (Outlook, etc) connected to the same account continue to work.
- Sign-in succeeds at https://www.onenote.com/stickynotes, on another Windows 10 v1809 PC (same software, same network, etc), and on an Android smartphone so the credentials aren't the problem.
- Resetting and reinstalling, as advised by https://www.easeus.com/resource/fix-sticky-notes-not-available-error-in-windows-10.html, doesn't make a difference.
- Manually entering the credentials, as opposed to selecting the account from the pre-filled menu, doesn't make a difference.
- Sign-in succeeds under a different local user profile.
- There's nothing relevant in the event log "Applications".
- Removing the Windows Credential "MicrosoftAccount:user=<my username / email address>" (modified today) didn't make a difference.
- Removing the Windows Credential "SSO_POP_User:user=<my username / email address>" (modified today) didn't make a difference.

**Update: 2019/09/23 11:19**

I have found that:

- Outlook 2019 has been acting strangely - prompting for my credentials every 1 hour or so but only actually needing them half the time, etc. A new Outlook profile doesn't seem to have made a difference.
- Clearing all Windows credentials (including `virtualapp/didlogical`, `SSO_POP_Device`, etc but excluding `Slack/tokens`) didn't make a difference.
- Using a different Office 365 account (but in the same tenant) works fine - it didn't even prompt for credentials.

**Update: 2019/09/23 12:29**

I have found that:

- Changing my password again hasn't made a difference.

Next, I'm going to try upgrading my installation of Windows 10.

**Update: 2019/09/24 12:38**

I have found that:

- Upgrading to Windows 10 v1903 hasn't made a difference. In fact, it's made it worse as it broke the installation of Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus so I had to online repair it which requires reactivation which is failing because of these authentication problems.

[image]

**Update: 2019/09/25 14:33**

I have found that:

- .OLD-ing my Windows user profile and re-signing in with the affected account to cause a temporary user profile to be generated fixed the Outlook problem but Sticky Notes wouldn't open.
- Attempting to use an app password wouldn't work because Modern Authentication can't handle them.
- Completely uninstalling Microsoft Office (Revo Uninstaller in advanced mode, .OLD-ing `%localAppData%\Microsoft\Outlook\`, clearing Credential Manager, removing all Outlook profiles, etc and reinstalling didn't make a difference. In fact, the Microsoft apps (Outlook, Sticky Notes, Edge, etc) were **still** aware of the accounts somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My last discovery reaffirmed my suspicion that modern Microsoft apps store credentials elsewhere so I looked around and found that the accounts were listed in Windows' `Settings` | `Accounts` | `Email & accounts`.

[image]
[image]

Removing the affected account from Windows' `Settings` | `Accounts` | `Access work or school` resolved the problem.